# Proper MQTT subscription code that maintains persistence

Tags: java, mqtt, subscribe

I am looking for a java code for MQTT client that subscribes to a given topic, every message published on that topic should reach the client only once.I have written many codes and in all the cases messages are delivered properly to the client when it is connected to the broker but if the subscribed client disconnects from the broker for some time and then again connects back, it does not receive the messages that were sent during the time that it was not connected and I have set the clean session flag also as false but still its not working, the code that I used is given below

```
import org.fusesource.hawtbuf.*;
import org.fusesource.mqtt.client.*;

/**
 * Uses an callback based interface to MQTT.  Callback based interfaces
 * are harder to use but are slightly more efficient.
 */
class Listener {

    public static void main(String []args) throws Exception {

        String user = env("APOLLO_USER", "admin");
        String password = env("APOLLO_PASSWORD", "password");
        String host = env("APOLLO_HOST", "localhost");
        int port = Integer.parseInt(env("APOLLO_PORT", "61613"));
        final String destination = arg(args, 1, "subject");


        MQTT mqtt = new MQTT();
        mqtt.setHost(host, port);
        mqtt.setUserName(user);
        mqtt.setPassword(password);
    mqtt.setCleanSession(false);
    mqtt.setClientId("newclient");

        final CallbackConnection connection = mqtt.callbackConnection();
        connection.listener(new org.fusesource.mqtt.client.Listener() {
            long count = 0;
            long start = System.currentTimeMillis();

            public void onConnected() {
            }
            public void onDisconnected() {
            }
            public void onFailure(Throwable value) {
                value.printStackTrace();
                System.exit(-2);
            }
            public void onPublish(UTF8Buffer topic, Buffer msg, Runnable ack) {
                System.out.println("Nisha Messages : " + msg);
                System.out.println("Nisha topic" + topic);
                System.out.println("Nisha Receive acknowledgement : " + ack);
                String body = msg.utf8().toString();
                if("SHUTDOWN".equals(body)) {
                    long diff = System.currentTimeMillis() - start;
                    System.out.println(String.format("Received %d in %.2f seconds", count, (1.0*diff/1000.0)));
                    connection.disconnect(new Callback<Void>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(Void value) {
                            System.exit(0);
                        }
                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(Throwable value) {
                            value.printStackTrace();
                            System.exit(-2);
                        }
                    });
                } else {
                    if( count == 0 ) {
                        start = System.currentTimeMillis();
                    }
                    if( count % 1000 == 0 ) {
                        System.out.println(String.format("Received %d messages.", count));
                    }
                    count ++;
                }
            }
        });
        connection.connect(new Callback<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Void value) {
                System.out.println("connected in :::: ");
                Topic[] topics = {new Topic(destination, QoS.AT_MOST_ONCE)};
                connection.subscribe(topics, new Callback<byte[]>() {
                    public void onSuccess(byte[] qoses) {
                    }
                    public void onFailure(Throwable value) {
                        value.printStackTrace();
                        System.exit(-2);
                    }
                });
            }
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Throwable value) {
                value.printStackTrace();
                System.exit(-2);
            }
        });

        // Wait forever..
        synchronized (Listener.class) {
            while(true)
                Listener.class.wait();
        }
    }

    private static String env(String key, String defaultValue) {
        String rc = System.getenv(key);
        if( rc== null )
            return defaultValue;
        return rc;
    }

    private static String arg(String []args, int index, String defaultValue) {
        if( index < args.length )
            return args[index];
        else
            return defaultValue;
    }
}
```

Am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score -1):

> it does not receive the messages that were sent during the time that it was not connected

MQTT **does not** retain all messages. If the client goes offline, undelivered messages are lost. The retain mechanism retains only the **last** message published to a topic.

You can [read more in the specs](http://docs.oasis-open.org/mqtt/mqtt/v3.1.1/os/mqtt-v3.1.1-os.html#_Toc398718038) point *3.3.1.3 RETAIN*

Comment: If a client connects with 'clean session' set to false, then qos 1/2 messages should get queued up for it whilst it is offline.

Comment: @knolleary Have you got any reference on this? AFAIK 'clean session' only keeps the subscriptions to the topics and not the messages (see: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_7.1.0/com.ibm.mq.doc/tt60370_.htm)

Comment: See conformance statement MQTT-3.1.2-5 in the standard: http://docs.oasis-open.org/mqtt/mqtt/v3.1.1/os/mqtt-v3.1.1-os.html#_Toc398718028

Comment: Thank you both for the reply.I found the answer, mqtt actually retains all the messages while the client is not connected if clean_session is set to false and I found a way to run my above program so that none of my messages are lost.

Comment: MQTT will be able to deliver the messages published during disconnected time to the subscribers if the QOS level is set to 1 or 2  and reconnection is done with clean session flag set to false.

Higher levels of QoS are more reliable, but involve higher latency and have higher bandwidth requirements.
0: The broker/client will deliver the message once, with no confirmation.
1: The broker/client will deliver the message at least once, with confirmation required.
2: The broker/client will deliver the message exactly once by using a four step handshake.
https://mosquitto.org/man/mqtt-7.html