# Why alive subscriber get only last published message

Tags: asp.net, mqtt, mosquitto, paho, m2m

**M2mqtt** incorporate in my asp.net **mvc** project. Face problem to synch subscribe informations.
[image]
When more than one clients published on one specific topic, client can subscribe them easily.

suppose in one situation when published happen then client is down/offline when he alive then only get the last published message not all published messages.
What to do?Is it a problem on MQTT?How alive client get all published messages.

M2mqtt connection with broker use by bellow syntax

```
 public static MqttClient SmartHomeMQTT { get; set; }

  SmartHomeMQTT = new MqttClient(brokerAddress, MqttSettings.MQTT_BROKER_DEFAULT_SSL_PORT, true, new X509Certificate(Resource.ca), null, MqttSslProtocols.TLSv1_2, client_RemoteCertificateValidationCallback);
  SmartHomeMQTT.Connect("6ea592c5-4b2f-481a-bb0a-eccbe8579d14", "####", "####", false, 3600);
```

**Note:**Connect method parameter four set to false for clean_session property but it's not work.

Comment: Take a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32967754/423955), answer and comments. Try setting `clean_session` flag to false, use the same client-id on reconnect, publish messages using QoS 1 or 2.

Answer (score 0):

To ensure that subscribers receive all messages, even ones that are published when they are offline (known as message persistence), you need to do a few things:

1. Make sure that 'Clean Session' is turned off in the subscribers
2. Ensure that each subscriber is using a unique Client ID
3. Use a QoS of 1 or 2

You don't say which MQTT server you are using, but you need to ensure that the server implementation supports it too.

Comment: thanks for your reply. I used bellow syntax as you say but it's not working.Please check my updated question description